# Binding the CTRL key to Crouch instead of C

Tags: borderlands-2, macos

When in the key bindings menu of the fully-updated Borderlands 2 Mac (Steam), I click on Crouch which is by default bound to **C**, the box pops up waiting for me to press the new key to bind. On Mac (OS X Mavericks), pressing the **Left Ctrl** does nothing -- it continues waiting for a key press. On Windows, it works as expected.

Has anyone found a way to work around this?

Comment: Is there a system shortcut that you can disable that is triggered by left Ctrl?

Comment: @NiteCyper: I'm able to bind the Ctrl key in other games, so it's unlikely that the OS is consuming the event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Karabiner**](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) with the following autogen:

```
<autogen>
  __KeyToKey__
  KeyCode::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::NONE,
  KeyCode::C
</autogen>
```

You can limit this to Borderlands with an appdef, and using `<only>BORDERLANDS</only>` above:

```
<appdef>
  <appname>BORDERLANDS</appname>
  <equal>{{bundleid}}</equal>
</appdef>
```

<sup>Replace `{{bundleid}}` with the bundle identifier of Borderlands 2.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify manually the keybindings in the `WillowInput.ini` file. In the mac version it is supposed to be on `~/Library/Preferences/Feral Interactive/` (or some subfolder that might be hidden).

You should add a line to the `[Engine.PlayerInput]` part, like

`Bindings=(Name="LeftControl",Command="Duck")`

It could also be "Crouch", I can't test it right now.

Let me know if it works, as I have the PC version of the game.

Comment: The file ~/Library/Application Support/borderlands 2/willowgame/Config/WillowInput.ini isn't being modified when key bindings are changed, so it looks like they are stored somewhere else (profile.bin maybe?). Can you try using this approach and verify that it works on the PC version?

Comment: I will look for the file that stores them. I'm assuming the above method didn't work out.